# How to enable MultiViews on Heroku?

Tags: php, apache2, heroku

I'm trying to enable `MultiViews` on an Heroku site, but I can't understand how to do it.

When I do it on servers I control, I do it on the `httpd.conf` file, but here I have to use it in a `Directory` block, and I don't know what to write there.

Simply trying:

```
<Directory "">
    Options Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
</Directory>
```

returns 500 "Directory not allowed here".

Without Directory instead it simply does nothing: the rest of the site works, and Multiviews stays disabled.